# Convolution using MPI to increase speed

Tags: c, mpi

I have this exercise where i need to use convolution on an array(100x100) using c language. Then i must use MPI to make my code faster. I already managed to do it with openMP but i can't figure out how to do it with MPI. The kernel array(3x3) i must use is shown on my code as "h". At the end of my code i sum the convoluted array to see the results. I also use omp_get_wtime because it's easy to use and calculate time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    const int COLL_SIZE = 100;
    const int ROW_SIZE = 100;
    int arr[ROW_SIZE][COLL_SIZE];
    int a [ROW_SIZE-2][COLL_SIZE-2];
    int k,j;
    double start_time, end_time, total_time;

    int h[3][3] = {
        {0, 1, 0},
        {1, -4, 1},
        {0, 1, 0}
    };

    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLL_SIZE; j++){
            arr[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    for(int x = 1; x < ROW_SIZE-1; x++){
        for(int y = 1; y < COLL_SIZE-1; y++){
            a[x-1][y-1] = 0;
            for(k = -1; k < 2; k++){
                for(j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                    a[x-1][y-1] += h[k+1][j+1] * arr[x-k][y-j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE-2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLL_SIZE-2; j++){           
            sum += a[i][j];
        }
    }
    end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    total_time = end_time - start_time; 
    printf("total time: %f\n", total_time);
    printf("sum is: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions to help me improve this code, if it's needed, or how i can i use MPI to make it parallel and faster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would broadcast h and scatter the arr. In worker i would perform operation and then a gatter.

Comment: @dntfury I would *not* broadcast it. That means you get a sequential bottlneck because you construct it on one process, and  you get communication overhead. For an idiomatic MPI program, let each process construct its own subset of the big array. That said, 100x100 is not big at all, and any speedup may drown in teh communication overhead. Maybe with 1000x1000 you'll see something.

Comment: Or simply define 'h' in worker nodes part to

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout So I should use scatter or scatterv to construct the subsets? My biggest concern is that I would get lost using MPI datatypes since this is really beginner level.

Comment: @dntfury So you would perform h in all the scattered sub_arrays? And then gather results.

Comment: 1. No, do not scatter anything. Build the data distributed. Each process takes care of a subset of the data, so it constructs its own subset prior to the computation. 2. This does not require any MPI datatypes: everything is contiguous subsets of arrays.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Ok, sorry for asking again but I am trying to understand and learn. So as you said no communications. I'm supposed to create arrays with the subset of the data I want on each process. I can do that with if statements if that is what you meant. Then perform h on the sub arrays.

Comment: in your code, `arr` is a constant array (all members are equal to `1`). Is this a mistake (for example, did you miss something when oversimplifiying your algorithm) ? If you build your data distributed as suggested by @VictorEijkhout, you will end up computing the sum of the `a` sub-array elements and then finally `MPI_Reduce()` (this is the only required communication).

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet Yeah just for now it's all equal to 1 for simplicity. If i understand correctly, distributing the data means don't create a single array but a piece of it on each process. Use h. Then get the sum of all sub arrays and use MPI_Reduce to get the total sum. But won't i lose the points that are on the edge of each array? If it was 1 array those points would be in the middle for example and i could use h. Now that they are located at the edge i can't since h doesn't fit. If that makes sense. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Some algo require what is called "ghost cells". That means an array divided in overlapping cells. But in this algo, I do not believe you need that.

Comment: Final remark: your main loops go from 1 to something, but then shift the index `[i-1][j-1]`. It's more C-idiomatic to start at zero. That makes the indexing expression also easier to read. If I see `i-1` I immediately wonder, oh, is there an `i+1` too somewhere? Anything unusual immediately makes the reader wonder if there is a deep reason for it.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout The indexing you refer to was provided by the exercise itself. That's why i left it as it is. I believe i solved my problem at some extent. Now each process holds its part of the new array named a. The only thing left to do is calculate time and see if there is any difference. I will leave the question active a little more and if everything is ok i will close it. Thank you for helping and providing a simple solution and instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Using Victor Eijkhout advice, I wrote this code which does the trick.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    const int COLL_SIZE = 100;
    const int ROW_SIZE = 100;
    int arr[ROW_SIZE][COLL_SIZE];
    int k,j, i, x, y, ssum;
    double start_time, end_time, total_time;
    int rank, num_procs;
    int h[3][3] = {
        {0, 1, 0},
        {1, -4, 1},
        {0, 1, 0}
    };
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    start_time = MPI_Wtime();
    for(i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(j=0; j<COLL_SIZE; j++){
            arr[i][j] = 1;
            //a random number to see the difference on sum
            if(i == 0 && j == 1){
                arr[i][j]= 100;
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);
    int sub_row_size = ROW_SIZE/num_procs;
    int a[sub_row_size][COLL_SIZE-2];
    int r = 0;
    for(x = rank+1; x < ROW_SIZE-1; x+=num_procs){
        for(y = 1; y < COLL_SIZE-1; y++){
            a[r][y-1] = 0;
            for(k = -1; k < 2; k++){
                for(j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                    a[r][y-1] += h[k+1][j+1] * arr[x-k][y-j];                   
                }   
            }
        }   
            r++;        
    }
    
    int sum = 0;
    //we have 98 cells divided by 4 procs 
    //the first 2 processes get 24 cells and the last 2 get 23 cells
    if(rank > 1){
        sub_row_size = (ROW_SIZE/num_procs)-1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sub_row_size; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COLL_SIZE-2; j ++){          
            sum += a[i][j];
        }
    }
    MPI_Reduce(&sum, &ssum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    sum = ssum;
    if(rank == 0){
        end_time = MPI_Wtime();
        total_time = end_time - start_time;
        printf("total time: %f\n", total_time);
        printf("sum is: %d\n", sum);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

For now it runs only on 4 processes but I will fix it soon to work on 2-16.
Maybe it's not perfect but it works and it's faster. Thank you all for your comments. They really helped me get into the logic.